# Differentiate between MSYS2 & Powershell/Command Prompt

Tags: python, msys2

I'm writing a python project which is not going to work on PowerShell or Command Prompt, but it does work on MSYS2.

Is there any way to differentiate between MSYS2 and PowerShell/Command Prompt?

I tried `os.name` and `sys.version`, but both return same result between these 3.

Comment: In what way it doesn't work? It might be better to test for the specific thing that causes it to not work, than in general for MSYS2.

Comment: Well, it can work, but it's a huge project with a bunch of dependencies, and many of them is extremely complicated to be built on PS/CMD... but anyway I've figured the answer out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining Abner Ham's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77959523/12427876) with `shellingham` module:

```
import shellingham

def provide_default():
    if 'MSYSTEM' in os.environ:
        return 'bash'
    elif 'PSModulePath' in os.environ:
        return 'powershell'
    elif 'SHELL' in os.environ:
        return 'bash'
    else:
        return 'cmd'

try:
    shell = shellingham.detect_shell()
except shellingham.ShellDetectionFailure:
    shell = provide_default()
if shell != 'bash':
    print(f"Shell detected: {shell}")
    print("Please use bash shell (Linux, MacOS, WSL, MSYS2, etc.) to run this script.")
    return
```